# What prevents a man in the middle attack when verifying a certificate with authority?

Tags: certificates, public-key-infrastructure, man-in-the-middle, certificate-authority

If a certificate looks suspicious you'd want to verify it with the authority.  As such you'll need to open a channel to the authority's verification server.  Who/what protects this verification channel against man in the middle attack?

Comment: This is not how it works.   You verify against the roots that are already installed on your system.  No communication required, for this very reason.  An active man-in-the-middle *can* block CRL or OSCP requests, but that's just a weakness in the system, and there are very few chances for a real attack to take advantage of this.

Comment: @Xander can you guide me to an answer on the root cert?

Comment: Your system, or browser has a root certificate store that contains all the roots the system trusts.  If the certificate being used is not ultimately signed by one of those roots, then is is untrusted.  There is no online protocol for checking/trusting an untrusted certificate.  The closest thing is revocation checking, as I mentioned in my first comment.

Comment: @Xander so how does the browser verify that the roots are authentic and not tampered with

Comment: Looks like this Wikipedia quote is the answer " Many software applications assume these root certificates are trustworthy on the user's behalf. For example, a web browser uses them to verify identities within TLS secure connections. However, this implies that the user trusts their browser's publisher, the certificate authorities it trusts, and any intermediates these certificate authorities may have issued a certificate-issuing-certificate, to faithfully verify the identity and intentions of all parties that own the certificates." So if I'm not wrong the ultimate Trust falls on web browser?

Comment: It depends.   For Firefox, for instance, yes, it has its own root store, and ultimately you're trusting Mozilla.  For Chrome, IE, and Edge on Windows, they use the Windows trust store, so you're trusting Microsoft.  For Safari and Chrome on macOS, you're trusting Apple.  On top of that, you're trusting yourself and your systems administrators if you have them, as you (and they) can also add and remove roots from the trust store.

Comment: @Allahjane An attacker who can replace the roots could also replace the code of your OS/browser. You always need some trusted platform to bootstrap from.

Answer (score 1):

> If a certificate looks suspicious you'd want to verify it with the authority. As such you'll need to open a channel to the authority's verification server.

No. TLS certificates are verified entirely locally. The certificate authorities' public keys are stored on your system (maintained by OS and browser vendors), and [public key cryptography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public-key_cryptography?wprov=sfla1) gives you the ability to verify that the certificate was signed by the corresponding *private* key.

The only thing close to what you're saying is [checking for revoked certificates](https://www.imperialviolet.org/2012/02/05/crlsets.html), which historically has involved a network check. Due to issues with an attacker being able to make those requests fail, Chrome at least now bundles revocations into its software updates.

Answer (score 0):

Since the browser stores root certificates, verification actually occurs on the client end. I would be more worried about replay attacks that could stem from an event such as a BGP hijack or DNS poisoning.. If you are a target for an advanced actor, you could theoretically be pointed to a fake site with a 'valid' certificate. The short answer is that there is not much protection from ssl MITM depending on the level of attack sophistication.